# for each value of one table get and display count number of coresponding values from another table

Tags: php, mysql

**unfortunately i have to do this in mysql / php** . I looked for three days, and there is like 10.000 explantions of this but NONE (and I repeat NONE) works for me. I tried it all. I have to ask, sorry.

I have two tables - articles and control.

```
table "articles"
    ------------------
    art_id  | name |
    ------------------
       1    | aaa  |
       2    | bbb  |
       3    | ccc  |
       4    | ddd  |

table "control"
    --------------------------------------------
    con_id | art_id  |      data      |
    --------------------------------------------
       1   |     1   |   something-a  |
       2   |     2   |   something-b  |
       3   |     1   |   something-a  |
       4   |     2   |   something-c  | 
       5   |     3   |   something-f  |
```

art_id exists in both tables. Now what i wanted - for query: 
`"select * from articles order by art_id ASC"` displayed in a table
to have also one cell displaying the count for each of art_id's from table CONTROL...
and so i tried join, left join, inner join - i get errors ... I also tried for each get only one result (for example 2 for everything)... this is semi-right but it displays the array of correct results and it's not even with join!!! :

```
$query = "SELECT art_id, count(*) as counting 
FROM control GROUP BY art_id ORDER BY con_id ASC"; 
$result = mysql_query($query); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['counting'];
}
```

this displays 221 -

```
-------------------------------------------------
art_id | name | count (this one from control) |
-------------------------------------------------
   1   |  aaa |   221   |
   2   |  bbb |   221   |
   3   |  ccc |   221   |
```

and it should be:

```
for art_id(value1)=2, 
for art_id(2)=2, 
for art_id(3)=1
```

it should be simple - like a count of values from CONTROL table displayed in query regarding the "articles" table...

The result query on page for table articles should be:
`"select * from articles order by art_id ASC"`

```
-------------------------------------------------
art_id | name | count (this one from control) |
-------------------------------------------------
   1   |  aaa |   2   |
   2   |  bbb |   2   |
   3   |  ccc |   1   |
```

So maybe i should go with JOIN or with join plus for each... Tried tha too, but then i'm not sure what is the proper thing to echo... all-in-all i'm completely lost here. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: "and so i tried join, left join, inner join - i get errors" - Can you elaborate on how your code "gets errors"? If you got an exception or error, please include the error message itself. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So imagine this in two steps:

1. Get the counts per `art_id` from the `control` table
2. Using your `articles` table, pick up the counts from step 1

That will give you a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT a.art_id, a.name, b.control_count
FROM articles a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT art_id, COUNT(*) AS control_count
    FROM control
    GROUP BY art_id
) b
ON a.art_id = b.art_id;
```

Which will give you the results you're looking for.

However, instead of using a subquery, you can do it all in one shot:

```
SELECT a.art_id, a.name, COUNT(b.art_id) AS control_count
FROM articles a
INNER JOIN control b
  ON a.art_id = b.art_id
GROUP BY a.art_id, a.name;
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0adfe/4)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(control.con_id) FROM control WHERE control.art_id = articles.art_id) AS count_from_con FROM articles ORDER BY art_id DESC;
```

If I understood your question right, this query should do the trick.

**Edit:** Created the tables you have described, and it works.

```
SELECT * FROM articles;
+--------+------+
| art_id | name |
+--------+------+
|      1 | aaa  |
|      2 | bbb  |
|      3 | ccc  |
|      4 | ddd  |
+--------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM control;
+--------+--------+------+
| con_id | art_id | data |
+--------+--------+------+
|      1 |      1 | NULL |
|      2 |      2 | NULL |
|      3 |      1 | NULL |
|      4 |      2 | NULL |
|      5 |      3 | NULL |
+--------+--------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(control.con_id) FROM control WHERE control.art_id = articles.art_id) AS count_from_con FROM articles ORDER BY art_id ASC;
+--------+------+----------------+
| art_id | name | count_from_con |
+--------+------+----------------+
|      1 | aaa  |              2 |
|      2 | bbb  |              2 |
|      3 | ccc  |              1 |
|      4 | ddd  |              0 |
+--------+------+----------------+
```

You haven't quite explained what you want to accomplish with the print out but here is an example in PHP: (Use [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) instead of `mysql_`)

```
$pdo = new PDO(); // Make your connection here
$stm = $pdo->query('SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(control.con_id) FROM control WHERE control.art_id = articles.art_id) AS count_from_con FROM articles ORDER BY art_id ASC');
while( $row = $stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) )
{
    echo "Article with id: ".$row['art_id']. " has " .$row['count_from_con'].' connected rows in control.';
}
```

Alternatively with the mysql_ extension:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(control.con_id) FROM control WHERE control.art_id = articles.art_id) AS count_from_con FROM articles ORDER BY art_id ASC');
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
    echo "Article with id: ".$row['art_id']. " has " .$row['count_from_con'].' connected rows in control.';
}
```

This should be enough examples to help you accomplish what you need.

Comment: @Ishas 
No, unfortunately it's not - i tried that before, still i get the array result 221. (I actually did made a mistake in typing, it should be ASC everywhere not desc, but that's of no importance for this i think). Still the problem is that the query has to recognize the art_id from articles and for each give a corresponding count from control :/

Comment: @djoric Edited the post with examples now. I have tested it and it works.

Comment: @Ishas ouch! that means i have an error after the query. Please - Can you please write me properly what i have to echo ; what goes after the query?

Comment: @djoric - That query should work.  What error are you getting?

Comment: @djoric Just added a PHP example with information about how you would print this.

Comment: @djoric Of course you get 221, you are just printing everything out, you dont print anything in betweeen. Try the PHP example at the bottom of my answer, you will get a completely different result.

Comment: @djoric Either way, just copy what is in the while-loop, it will work with your code as well.

Comment: @djoric I don't mean change the database, just the php extension you use to connect to MySQL. The `mysql_` functions are deprecated. You could also use the `mysqli_` extension.

Comment: @Ishas 
no... error... something is not right here with me. however i see your point. I really do.

Comment: @djoric Just added another example, this time with the old extension. Try that one, if it does not work for you, I can not help you. You are getting the right results, you just need to decide how you want to use them.

Comment: No. I made mistake. Thank you!

Comment: @djoric - If this answer helped solve your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) using the check mark under the voting arrows.  Thank you!